# How to separate vuex modules without separating state, mutatation, getters of this module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

What the tittle means?

I want to create modules into single files. It means that I want to create a single file of the module which contains everything: state, mutations, getters and actions.

Let's see the code, and what I tried to do:

**store/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import global from "./modules/global";

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    contactInfo: false
  },
  mutations: {
    showContactInfo: state => state.contactInfo = true
  },
  getters: {
    getContactInfo: state => state.contactInfo
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
    global
  }
});
```

**store/modules/global.js**

```
const global = {
    state: {
        mobileView: false
    },

    mutations: {
        setMobileView: (state) => state.mobileView = true
    },

    getters: {
        getMobileView: (state) => state.mobileView
    }
}

export default global;
```

Everything with this code is well - 0 errors

But when I open vue dev tools, get into vuex tab I can see that the state of the "global" is just an empty object.

Actually I don't know why this is not working. Or whether is that a good practice to create modules that contains everything in only one file.

Comment: I was so dramatical to share it here. It was just a problem with the dev tools, after reload it everything working well -.-

Comment: right. but it's also not common practice to call `Vue.use(Vuex)` here but rather in `main.js` where other Vue plugins are also "installed"